# "name 'ventas' is not defined

Tags: python

La cuestión es que en este ejercicio tengo que crear un menú con 5 opciones para el usuario.

1. Compra
2. Venta
3. Alquiler
4. Mostrar Datos
5. Salir

Una vez elegida la opción de menú, en cada apartado tengo que guardar el/los dato/s introducidos por el usuario en una lista. Y, como veis, en la opción 4 lo que se me pide es que se muestren todas las listas (con los datos almacenados, si los hay).
Cuando ejecuto el programa todo va bien hasta que pulso 4. Si he pasado por todas las opciones del menú y he introducido un dato en cada una, se ejecuta bien y me muestra las 3 listas [compra, venta, alquileres] con sus respectivos datos. Pero si dejo alguna de las listas en blanco ya me da error. Y me dice, por ejemplo: "name 'ventas' is not defined.

Lo estoy ejecutando en Jupyter, pero por las dudas he copiado el código en Visual Studio, y tb me hace cosas raras.
Como supondréis, visto el código, aun no puedo hacer uso de funciones ni nada muy sofisticado.

CÓDIGO:

```
print("MENÚ COMPRA-VENTA")
while(True):
    print("""
    1. Comprar
    2. Vender
    3. Alquilar
    4. Mostrar listas de datos
    5. Salir
    Introduzca que desea hacer (1-4)""")
    opcion = input()
    if opcion == '1':
        print("¿Qué desea comprar?")
        compra_usuario = input()
        compras = ["COMPRAS ":] 
        compras.append(compra_usuario)
    elif opcion == '2':
        print("¿Qué desea vender?")
        venta_usuario = input()
        ventas = ["VENTAS: "]
        ventas.append(venta_usuario)
    elif opcion == '3':
        print("¿Qué desea alquilar?")
        alquiler_usuario = input()
        alquileres = ["ALQUILERES: "]
        alquileres.append(alquiler_usuario)
    elif opcion == '4':
        listas = [compras, ventas, alquileres]
        print(listas)
    elif opcion == '5':
        print("¡Gracias por su interés!\nSaliendo del Programa...")
        break
    else:
        print("Comando desconocido. Vuelva a intentarlo.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se pulsa 4 despues de haber introducido por lo menos una compra, una venta y una alquiler no hay ningun problema como ves:

```
MENÚ COMPRA-VENTA

    1. Comprar
    2. Vender
    3. Alquilar
    4. Mostrar listas de datos
    5. Salir
    Introduzca que desea hacer (1-4)
1
¿Qué desea comprar?
leche 

    1. Comprar
    2. Vender
    3. Alquilar
    4. Mostrar listas de datos
    5. Salir
    Introduzca que desea hacer (1-4)
2
¿Qué desea vender?
huevos

    1. Comprar
    2. Vender
    3. Alquilar
    4. Mostrar listas de datos
    5. Salir
    Introduzca que desea hacer (1-4)
3
¿Qué desea alquilar?
patatas

    1. Comprar
    2. Vender
    3. Alquilar
    4. Mostrar listas de datos
    5. Salir
    Introduzca que desea hacer (1-4)
4
[['COMPRAS :', 'leche'], ['VENTAS: ', 'huevos'], ['ALQUILERES: ', 'patatas']]

    1. Comprar
    2. Vender
    3. Alquilar
    4. Mostrar listas de datos
    5. Salir
    Introduzca que desea hacer (1-4)
5
¡Gracias por su interés!
Saliendo del Programa...
```

El problema es que cuando pulsas 4 antes de haber introducido una venta todavia no has definido la lista `ventas` asi que no existe ningun objeto con el nombre `ventas`.

Puedes evitarlo definando todas las listas al prinicipio del codigo:

```
print("MENÚ COMPRA-VENTA")

compras = ["COMPRAS :"] 
ventas = ["VENTAS: "]
alquileres = ["ALQUILERES: "]

while(True):
    print("""
    1. Comprar
    2. Vender
    3. Alquilar
    4. Mostrar listas de datos
    5. Salir
    Introduzca que desea hacer (1-4)""")
    opcion = input()
    if opcion == '1':
        print("¿Qué desea comprar?")
        compra_usuario = input()
        compras.append(compra_usuario)
    elif opcion == '2':
        print("¿Qué desea vender?")
        venta_usuario = input()
        ventas.append(venta_usuario)
    elif opcion == '3':
        print("¿Qué desea alquilar?")
        alquiler_usuario = input()
        alquileres.append(alquiler_usuario)
    elif opcion == '4':
        listas = [compras, ventas, alquileres]
        print(listas)
    elif opcion == '5':
        print("¡Gracias por su interés!\nSaliendo del Programa...")
        break
    else:
        print("Comando desconocido. Vuelva a intentarlo.")
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ahora me parece algo obvio, pero me he pasado buena pare de la tarde tratando de solucionarlo. Son estas cosas que tienes delante de ti, pero cuando eres novato no ves. Tengo que acostumbrarme a hacer la trazabilidad de código para dar con ello por mi mismo ¡De nuevo un millón de gracias!